# Unable to use NavigationPage animation Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here I am using 
https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/xamarin-forms-page-transitions

This process is working fine
but I have a master details page,so when I am setting the master details page as parent Page then its not working

This Sample uses the Navigation Page as Parent page 
Example:
App.xaml.cs

```
MainPage= new Controls.TransitionNavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

its working fine
but I have a master details page and I am unable to use master details page with this sample

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The package uses custom `NavigationPageRenderer`. `MasterDetailPage` uses different renderers (on iOS there are two of them, one for iPad and one for iPhone). What you need to do is to create custom renderers for those, for Android it would be for the class `MasterDetailPageRenderer` and then port that code to those renderers.

It shouldn't be too hard, but not trivial.